# Required Validator Error Message Display

Tags: asp.net, validation

I'm having an issue with a standard ASP.NET portal.
Suppose that has a TextBox and a RequiredFieldValidator. I want the validator only shows the error message when I input a wrong format text.
[image: sample]
However the current issue is even I haven't input nothing, it displays the message. After I type the correct text, it disappeared then.
 My code:

```
<tr>
                    <td>
                        *First Name:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="FirstName" MaxLength="50" />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="FirstName"
                            ErrorMessage="First Name is required." EnableClientScript="True" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
```

The code behind is something like

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Validate();
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            // blah
        }

    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what the RequiredFieldValidator is *supposed* to do. Use another type of validator such as a RegularExpressionValidator or a CustomValidator.

Also how do you define the correct format for a person's name?

Comment: No special requirement for user name.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to use `RegularExpressionValidator` not `RequiredFieldValidator`.
Let us say you want your textbox to accept only alphanumeric characters, you may set the format this way:

```
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="val1" runat="server" ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"/>
```